# To make an impression + of?

Tags: prepositions, idioms

Would it be correct "he makes an impression **of** an honest politician" meaning he seems to be an honest politician?

I'm sorry if my question duplicates any of the previous questions. Thanks!

Comment: I would say "he *gives the* impression of an honest politician" or "he makes an impression *on* an honest politician", though they don't mean the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

If you use impression to mean an idea or appearance that may be false,
you usually say:

He gave the impression of an honest politician.

You usually make an impression on somebody that means you do something in such a way that it causes them to notice and admire you such as "His performance made an impression on everybody.

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

"He gives off the impression that he is an honest politician." is probably the most clear translation.

But I would just say something like "He seems like an honest politician."

But all of these are oxymorons. [Joke]

Comment: Thank you! Yes, "honest politician" is an oxymoron :)